# Session block not working

Tags: php

I am new to programming and am experimenting with sessions. I believe the code I have written is correct but after spending time trying to wrap my head around the concept, I am not able to figure out why the program isn't working.

When I debugged the code in the `session-page.php`, control goes to `if(isset...)` but then instead of entering the code block or showing a submit button on the browser, simply moves to the next session variable. Someone please be kind enough to explain it to me why this thing ain't working.

Also, can I not use `<form>` and simply use `isset($_GET[ ])`?

session-page.php[CODE]

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
    $_SESSION['xyz']="Hello World";
}
$_SESSION['abc']="Hey Buddy!";
?>

<form method="post">
<a href="test-page.php"><input type='submit' name='sub' value='redirect'></a>
</form>
```

test-page.php[CODE]

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['xyz']!="Hello World")
{
    header("location:session-page.php");    
}
echo $_SESSION['abc'];
?>
```

Comment: there is no `action` in the form, its incomplete..add one and report back..and remove the link that's not how you submit forms..

Comment: @Gntem, still not working

Comment: Remove the `<a href="test-page.php"></a>` around the input. Should just be `<input type='submit' name='sub' value='redirect'>`. Then the form action would be `action="test-page.php"`

Comment: @Rasclatt, not working after removing the links and adding action to the form.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the action should just be self or `action="#"`

Comment: You need to submit the form to `session-page.php` so that `$_SESSION['xyz']` gets set. Once you have submitted the form once, you can then go to `test-page.php` to see the text "Hey Buddy!"

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe, remove link (leave only button) but form action put @session-page.php@ or leave blank.

Comment: @Rasclatt if I remove the links and leave the action as #, how I am supposed to redirect to test-page.php?

Comment: The logic is messed up a bit. You want to post to the same page to set the session (as you have it), then redirect to the second page to echo it. See my answer.

Comment: @Nicolai, it is working, thanks bud. Plz tell me something, if I remove the <form> and simply use isset($_GET[ ]), is it going to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have this type of workflow (based on what you currently have):

**/session-page.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST['sub'])) {
    $_SESSION['xyz'] = "Hello World";
    header('Location: test-page.php');
    exit;
}
if(empty($_SESSION['abc']))
    $_SESSION['abc']="Hey Buddy!";
?>

<form method="post" action="#">
    <input type='submit' name='sub' value='redirect'>
</form>
```

**/test-page.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['xyz'] != "Hello World") {
    header("location:session-page.php");    
    exit;
}

echo $_SESSION['abc'];
?>
```

Comment: Probably you mean `header('location:test-page.php');` instead of `header('test-page.php');`

Comment: Thanks, yeah... I do mean that!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rasclatt

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nicolai

Comment: I made one copy/paste error. you probably want `if(empty($_SESSION['abc']))` on the first page to set the `abc` value or else it won't set it on page load.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<form method="post" action="" >
<input type='submit' name='sub'value='redirect'>
</form>
```